# getting the error : 2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, activeadmin

i am trying to implement `active admin`with the following configuration.

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.7.1'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'

# Plus integrations with:
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan' # or cancancan
gem 'draper'
gem 'pundit'
```

i am using `ruby 2.2.2`

i am unable to do `bundle install`. getting the following error:

```
prashanth@prashanth-OptiPlex-390:~/rails_apps/admin_interface$ rvm use 2.2.2
Using /home/prashanth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2
prashanth@prashanth-OptiPlex-390:~/rails_apps/admin_interface$ rvm gemset create 222admin
ruby-2.2.2 - #gemset created /home/prashanth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@222admin
ruby-2.2.2 - #generating 222admin wrappers........
prashanth@prashanth-OptiPlex-390:~/rails_apps/admin_interface$ rvm use 2.2.2@222admin
Using /home/prashanth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2 with gemset 222admin
prashanth@prashanth-OptiPlex-390:~/rails_apps/admin_interface$ bundle
/home/prashanth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
    from /home/prashanth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:7:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Do this: `gem install bundler`.

Comment: i did that as well. still its giving the same error.